# Sending an Activation Email when a New User Registers

Tags: php

The code below is a login system that I am using.  It is supposed to allow a new user to register and then send the new user an activation email.  It is inserting the new user into the MySQL database, but it is not sending the activation email.  Any ideas why it's not sending the activation email?

Thanks in advance,

John

header.php:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0); 
session_start();
require_once ('db_connect.inc.php'); 
require_once ("function.inc.php"); 
$seed="0dAfghRqSTgx"; 
$domain =  "...com"; 


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>The Sandbox - <?php echo $domain; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sandbox.css"> 
<div class="hslogo"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/"><img src="images/hslogo.png" alt="Example" border="0"/></a></div>
</head>
<body>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    // user is not logged in.
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        // retrieve the username and password sent from login form & check the login.
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();
        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {
        // User is not logged in and has not pressed the login button
        // so we show him the loginform
        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{
    // The user is already loggedin, so we show the userbox.
    show_userbox();
}
?>


function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'"> 

    <div class="usernameformtext"><label title="Username">Username: </label></div> 
    <div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></div> 


    <div class="passwordformtext"><label title="Password">Password: </label></div> 
    <div class="passwordformfield"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></div> 


    <div class="registertext"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/register.php" title="Register">Register</a></div> 
    <div class="lostpasswordtext"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></div> 

  <p class="loginbutton"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';


}
```

register.php:

```
<?php

require_once "header.php"; 

if (isset($_POST['register'])){

    if (registerNewUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password2'], $_POST['email'])){

        echo "<div class='registration'>Thank you for registering, an email has been sent to your inbox, Please activate your account.
        <a href='http://www...com/sandbox/index.php'>Click here to login.</a>
        </div>";

    }else {

        echo "Registration failed! Please try again.";
        show_registration_form();

    }

} else {
// has not pressed the register button
    show_registration_form();   
}


?>
```

New User Function:

```
function registerNewUser($username, $password, $password2, $email)
{

    global $seed;

    if (!valid_username($username) || !valid_password($password) || 
            !valid_email($email) || $password != $password2 || user_exists($username))
    {
        return false;
    }


    $code = generate_code(20);
    $sql = sprintf("insert into login (username,password,email,actcode) value ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password . $seed))
        , mysql_real_escape_string($email), mysql_real_escape_string($code));


    if (mysql_query($sql))
    {
        $id = mysql_insert_id();

        if (sendActivationEmail($username, $password, $id, $email, $code))
        {

            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }

    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Send Activation Email function:

```
function sendActivationEmail($username, $password, $uid, $email, $actcode)
{
    global $domain;
    $link = "http://www.$domain/sandbox/activate.php?uid=$uid&actcode=$actcode";
    $message = "
Thank you for registering on http://www.$domain/,

Your account information:

username:  $username
password:  $password

Please click the link below to activate your account.

$link

Regards
$domain Administration
";

    if (sendMail($email, "Please activate your account.", $message, "no-reply@$domain"))
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @John. Is sendMail a custom function or not? If not, the function to send email is mail as stated in answer 1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the function for sending email is [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and not sendMail? If the function sendMail is defined maybe there is an error in that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mail($email, "Please activate your account.", $message, "no-reply@$domain"))
{
    return true;
} else
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to needing to use the [`mail`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function as mentioned by others, which is your primary problem, there is a small problem with this:

```
"no-reply@$domain"
```

PHP is expecting a header:

```
"From: no-reply@$domain"
```

or

```
"Reply-To: no-reply@$domain"
```

This isn't the reason your script is failing (as mentioned above, it's using the wrong function), but it is still important to comply with the standards or else things may break when you don't expect them to.